# online editor alike eclipse for sapui5/openui5?

Tags: eclipse, editor, sapui5

Because of my low system hardware(celeron dual core) I found hard to work with eclipse+tomcat. The purpose is learning to develop in sapui5/openui5 and I haven't found an online editor like eclipse. My main interest is to have the posibility to "chain" multiple views, controllers, thing that I can't do(or don't know how) in jsbin or jsfiddle. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the SAPUI5 WebIDE?

http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-58926

The latest version is a simple installation and is a little lighter that a full eclipse install.

Other options include using a plain editor like Sublime Text and a local webserver using node.js.

As described in this tweet:

[@ui5io](https://twitter.com/ui5io) with node it's "npm install -g nws" and then "nws" in the sdk directory— Christian Grail (@cgrail) [9 October 2015](https://twitter.com/cgrail/status/652348381184987136)